# Which muxer has the lowest overhead for solely audio?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am muxing audio only mp3float datastream to rtmp, what muxer is the least resource intensive?

I am using flv right now, it works, I was wondering about efficiency of operation.

Comment: @ScottStensland That is a shame, that kind of information is invaluable to creating low latency streaming services.  I will stick with flv

Comment: If you are using rtmp, flv is your only option.